# I am having a FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: umo.com.players, PID: 29401

Tags: java, android

I am having a  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: umo.com.players, PID: 29401
How do you solve the error of Fatal Exception
I have never had any kind of this error
I need to try and finish this project  java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
here is my logcat
Please help

```
2020-10-14 15:52:11.691 29401-29401/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: umo.com.players, PID: 29401
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
    at umo.com.players.Home.ChatFragment$2.onDataChange(ChatFragment.java:98)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source:13)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZV(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source:63)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6739)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

here is chat fragment

```
public class 
     ChatFragment 
      extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private UserAdapter userAdapter;
private List<User> mUsers;

FirebaseUser fuser;
DatabaseReference reference;

private List<String> usersList;



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    usersList = new ArrayList<>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chats");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            usersList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

                if (chat.getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())){
                    usersList.add(chat.getReceiver());
                }
                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(fuser.getUid())){
                    usersList.add(chat.getSender());
                }
            }
            readchats();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

private void readchats() {
    mUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mUsers.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                for (String id : usersList){
                    if (user.getUser_id().equals(id)){
                        if (mUsers.size() !=0 ){
                            for (User user1 : mUsers){
                                if (!user.getUser_id().equals(user1.getUser_id())){
                                    mUsers.add(user);

                                }
                            }
                        }else {
                            mUsers.add(user);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `ConcurrentModificationException` because you are trying to modify the list inside the for loop.
This can be solved in several ways:

1. You can use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) as a type for `mUsers` list.
2. Or you can just create new List to be used inside the loop

   `for (User user1 : new ArrayList<>(mUsers)){...}`
3. Or you can solve it in more economical way by adding temporary list for new items

```
List<User> usersToBeAdded = new ArrayList<User>();
for (User user1 : mUsers){
    if (!user.getUser_id().equals(user1.getUser_id())){
        usersToBeAdded.add(user);
}}
mUsers.addAll(usersToBeAdded);
```

Answer (score 1):

This exception means that you are attempting to structurally modify a list while some piece of code is in the process of iterating it.

This is the default behavior of the `ArrayList` and can be backed up by the following piece of documentation:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
> methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
> time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
> iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
> ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
> modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
> risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
> in the future.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed
> as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees
> in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast
> iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort
> basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended
> on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of
> iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

Link to the document in question [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator%28%29).

Now from what I can tell from the share code, you can a common list named

`private List<String> usersList;`

Which you modify here:

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            usersList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

                if (chat.getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())){
                    usersList.add(chat.getReceiver());
                }
                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(fuser.getUid())){
                    usersList.add(chat.getSender());
                }
            }
            readchats();
        }
```

There are two kind of modifications here:

1. Clearing the list
2. Adding new elements

At the same time you iterate the list in question in this code segment:

```
 for (String id : usersList){
                    if (user.getUser_id().equals(id)){
                        if (mUsers.size() !=0 ){
                            for (User user1 : mUsers){
                                if (!user.getUser_id().equals(user1.getUser_id())){
                                    mUsers.add(user);

                                }
                            }
                        }else {
                            mUsers.add(user);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Since both piece of code are executed in an asynchronous manner, there is no guarantee that someone will be modifying the list while someone else will be iterating over it.

I suggest you revisit your code to address this or find some other way of iterating the list in question.

Comment: Do you know any other way I can iterate the list in question in this code

Comment: There are various ways to address this problem. One would be to iterate over a copy of the original list. Another would be use an iterator. Search online and you can find various ways of addressing this. My answer regarded the explanation of the original problem. I hope you understood its nature.